# jQuery validation: form always valid issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, validation

i am trying to perfom form validation before submit to server. I am using jquery.validate plugin 
([JQuery validation plugin page](http://jqueryvalidation.org))
The problem i am facing is that does not matter what i type in the form fields, validation always succeded, i double checked everything against documentation and samples over the wire and cannot see why i am getting this behaviour.
This form is loaded via jquery ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "mypage.php",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    success: function(cont){
        $("body").append(cont);
    }
});
```

Here i show you mypage.php code

```
<script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#frmParticipante").validate({
        rules: { 
            nombre: {  required: true  } ,
            email: { required: true, email: true },
            ci: { required: true}
        }
    });

    $("#frmParticipante").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();  
        if($(this).valid()){
            loadpop("ganaste.php");
        }
    else
        loadpop("perdiste.php");    

    });
});


</script>

<div id="pop_terminaste" class="pop_mensaje ingresardatos animated fadeInDown">
    <div id="infopop">
        <div id="lady"> <img src="images/terminaste1.jpg" width="453" height="626" /> </div>
        <div id="dato">
            <p class="txt1">¡Terminaste la trivia!</p>
            <p class="txt2">Ahora solo te falta completar tus datos para conocer el resultado.</p>
            <p class="txt3">Si ha cargado anteriormente sus datos, ingresar solo su cédula.</p>
            <form action="" id="frmParticipante" class="form">
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="nombre"><img src="images/ico_nombre.png" alt="ico_nombre" /></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido" id="nombre">
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="email"><img src="images/ico_email.png" alt="ico_email" /></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email">
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="ci"><img src="images/ico_ci.png" alt="ico_ci" /></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="C.I" id="ci">
                </fieldset>
                <p class="msg error">Favor verificar los datos ingresados.</p>                
                <input type="submit" value="VER RESULTADOS" />                    
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: There is an error in your first jQuery code sample `"mypage.php` is missing the closing `"`.

Comment: You need to `return false;` inside `$("#frmParticipante").submit` to prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: @KhanhTO or `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Sébastien you are right about "mypage.php", this was a mistake while typing in here
KhanhTO, I had tested using  e.preventDefault() with the same result, putting that line there does not changes the result, the form is passing validation anyway
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am pretty sure that the validation library requires name attributes and doesn't pay attention to id attributes.  You should either change your id attr's to name, or just add name attributes with the same values...like :

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido" id="nombre" name="nombre">
```

Here is a fiddle to show that it works http://jsfiddle.net/7WTvL/1/

Along with the names, you will likely need to load your validate.js library in the head of the page you are loading the form into, and then run validate in .done() on your ajax request.

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: "mypage.php",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false
}).done(function(cont) {
    $("body").append(cont);
    $("#frmParticipante").validate({
        rules: { 
            nombre: {  required: true  } ,
            email: { required: true, email: true },
            ci: { required: true}
        }
    });
});
$("#frmParticipante").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  
    if($(this).valid()){
        loadpop("ganaste.php");
    }
    else
        loadpop("perdiste.php");    
});
</script>
```

Again...make SURE the validate library is loaded on the page you're ajax'ing content into...it needs to be on the page before your ajax'd content arrives.

Comment: kevindeleon, tryied your suggestion and did not worked, same result. Thanks

Comment: Can you put up a fiddle or give an example URL so that we can try to help you out, Cheers.

Comment: I put a fiddle up, and it works fine for me if you add names like I said. http://jsfiddle.net/7WTvL/1/

Comment: The only other thing I can think is that it is a timing issue with your document.ready and when you are pulling in your form from ajax...the form may not exist on the page when the validation library does it's initializing.

Comment: hey kevin, i just tested http://jsfiddle.net/ElioB/ZjjQd/2/ and noticed the same, if the problem is timing issue i thing that i have to get rid of the plugin and validate manually. Have you any other sugestion? Thanks very much

Comment: Kevin, i made the changes and now it seems like the plugin is not loaded or is no reconized by the ajax loaded php page, firebug show me the following error in the script
"TypeError: $(...).valid is not a function
if($(this).valid()){"
I placed the plugin import in head of the content page into which mypage.php is loaded.
Thanks

Comment: I added a new fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/NF2jz/4579/  This shows that it should work with the updated code using ajax (obviously you should ignore my ajax, because you won't be using the /html/echo url and what not.  That is a fiddle convention...but it's more of a proof of concept.  I would move your validate library import around to make sure it is loading BEFORE your ajax'd content, but after jQuery.  Outside of that, I am at a loss.